# Why is the cursorline always showing after the cursor moves over a line?

Tags: macvim, macos

Can anyone can help me, my vim always shows the cursorline, like this:

[image: 14 lines of underlined text]

I have  `set nocursorline` in the ~/.vimrc, but it has no effect.

vim version is: 7.4.622

[image: VIM Version 7.4.622]

vim is run on OSX 10.10.3, how to remove the white line.

Comment: This doesn't look like the cursorline. It's probably something in your vimrc file. See: [How do I debug my vimrc file?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51).

Comment: I've seen something similar in the past.  I never got to the root cause of it, but I'm pretty sure it was related to a font problem, not to Vim.

Comment: @lcd047 Thanks for your hint. I change my font size from 18 to 19, and it works. I agree that it's a font problem.

Comment: @lutaoact maybe you could answer your own question so as it doesn't stay unanswered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's font problem, not vim. I change my font size from 18 to 19, and it works. You can make it as what I have done. I didn't change the font of vim, I just change the font size of terminal.

Comment: To be more useful to other people you could also indicate how you changed the size of your font ;) If I remember well on gVim and MacVim it is with the option `guifont`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my OS X terminal on both vim and neovim.
Scrolling up showed the cursor lines on all the lines I had moved up.
Through a little bit of trial and error, I narrowed it down to the following lines

```
" highlight current line
set cul                                                                                                                                                     
" adjust color
highlight CursorLine ctermbg=LightBlue cterm=None term=None
set bg=dark
```

Moving the 'bg=dark' line above the cursorline configuration fixed it for me.

```
set bg=dark

" highlight current line
set cul                                                                                                                                                     
" adjust color
highlight CursorLine ctermbg=LightBlue cterm=None term=None
```