# Stray characters when scrolling in gvim

Tags: gvim, scrolling, mouse

When scrolling with the mouse wheel, characters will often duplicate themselves on subsequent lines. For instance, if I'm scrolling down, I can sometimes see an open brace on its line and on the following line. I can clean this up each time with Ctrl+L, but how can I prevent it from occurring at all?

Comment: It could be a font problem. In this [question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3340/why-is-the-cursorline-always-showing-after-the-cursor-moves-over-a-line) changing the font size resolved a similar problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue running gvim 7.4 on win10. Upgrading to gvim8.0 fixed this problem for me.